# User Wordpress menu in custom page

Tags: customization, menus

I have a third party app installed (such as a forum) that I've linked with my Wordpress menu (as a custom link). However I wish to show the same wordpress menu above this app (I have it's source code so can make changes). What do I need to do so it shows up nicely on any page?

Right now clicking on it opens the new page but naturally without the current theme. I'd love for it to maintain the same overall look if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to load in the external wordpress library first, and then you can call the admin bar.

```
// Load the external Wordpress files
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( './wp-load.php' );
```

and then call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` accordingly to load the relevant display code.